# Strong names, and their relationship to referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reference

Here's the problem I have. I need to inherit from two classes in C#, which can't be done. So I've set my class to inherit from one class and implement an interface for the other. I did the interface first, and all worked well. Then issues started arising when inheriting from the class. At first, it would compile, but on implementing the class I would get:

```
The assembly 'XXXXXXX\bin\x86\Debug\Resource.dll' does not have a strong name.
```

Easy enough, I signed my projects. But now I get an issue when building with my references that were working before:

```
The type 'WPResourceEvtLib.IWPResourceEvt' is defined in an assembly that is not
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Interop.WPResourceEvtLib,
Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=567474567455'
```

I have WPResourceEvtLib.tlb which has been registered, and a Interop.WPResourceEvtLib.dll, whoch shouldn't be required. And if I add the Interop.WPResourceEvtLib.dll to the references I get:

```
Cannot embed interop type 'WPResourceEvtLib.tagWPResErrorType' found in both assembly
'XXXXXXX\Interop.WPResourceEvtLib.dll' and
'XXXXXXX\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.WPResourceEvtLib.dll'. Consider setting the 'Embed
 Interop Types' property to false.
```

This is .net3.5, so there is no 'Embed Interop Types' option, but I did find those options in the cproj files - they did nothing though. I'm either so very close, or I'm completely wrong in my implementation. What could it be?

Comment: You might have tried mostly , clean and build the solution . Is the version of WPResourceEvtLib.IWPResourceEvt same 1.0.0.0 , is it set to use a specific version?

Comment: do you need to use COM? Is any of your code written in a non .Net language?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a mostly non-answer, but the amount of supporting questions got large, and that way it will be more readable.

First, what is the nature/kind of `XXXXXXX\bin\x86\Debug\Resource.dll`? If .Net, then why TLB file? Is it COM and native? Or COM/OCX? Or just a normal .Net assembly with some ComVisible types? What is `WPResourceEvtLib`? Is it the "name" of that `Resource.dll`?

"Back then", when your assemblies were not signed, everything worked fine? What exactly have you changed? Which project got signed and what are the relations/references between the projects? Are all those projects inside the same solution and are they built simultaneously and they do reference-by-sibling-project, or maybe you build some parts separately and only reference-by-GAC, or, worse, reference-by-path-to-DLL? It might be just that you forgot to refresh/rebuild some references and they still link to the old unsigned versions?

Finally, why do you think that your implementation of inheritance and interface caused anything? Did you do some low-level stuff like manually writing IL, COM metadata, etc? The only thing the inheritance/implementation problem could actually cause is to force you to reference an assembly X to get the definition of the base class and assembly Y for the definition of interface, nothing more. It has nothing to do with signing or being unsigned. It all just about references to correct assemblies.

Let's start guessing. So, back to the references. First error message tells you that, your project references assembly X that was using another assembly Y and your project tries to use a class/type that belongs to Y but without explicitely referencing the Y (ie. it peeked it from X assembly). It cannot be done. When T.dll uses X.dll that uses Y.dll, whenever X.dll returns a Y-type to the client from T.dll, the T.dll must reference the Y.dll or else it will not be able to use that Y-object. Now note the change: when unsigned, everything worked. So your project "unsigned T" had used "unsigned X" which used "unsigned Y". If that compiled, it means that T reffed both X and Y. After signing you got error that "signed T" does not reference "signed Y".  How did does SEE the new signed Y? If it REFERENCED it, then the error would not show up. Hence, it means that "signed T" has indeed referenced "signed X" which indeed is referencing "signed Y". BUT: as the error claims that signed T does not reference signed Y, it may mean that the signed T project is still referencing **the old unsigned Y**. Now if you actually add the reference to the signed Y, you will get a type clash: same types will be visible in old unsigned Y and new signed Y. Hey, everything seems to fit.

It might have happened if you **added a reference from T to a Y.dll by path** and **forgot to rebuild that Y.dll at that path**. That can be really silly: i.e. in T you have clicked "add reference" and "browse" and pointed to "Release\Y.dll", and then forgot to rebuild it and only have rebuild the T/X/Y in DEBUG modes. That way, one old unsigned version would linger in the cache directories and the T would still try to use it, while the referenced X would already be relinked to new signed Y.

have you tried the simpliest possible thing: clean everything, delete all bin/obj folders, remove all references, add the references back and rebuild?